# PicoCLI : How can I use @ArgGroup for a method?

Tags: picocli

I want to have mutually exclusive command options for the below snippet :

```
@Command(description = "test command")
public void test(
        @Option(names = { "-a"}, required = true, arity = "0", description = "print A") boolean a,
        @Option(names = { "-b"}, required = true, description = "pint B") boolean b) 

    // 
}
```

If I use @ArgGroup for a class field then It works but I want to achieve the same for methods.

```
class TestClass{

@ArgGroup(exclusive = true, multiplicity = "1")
private Sample sample = new Sample();

public static class Sample {
    @Option(names = { "-a"}, required = true, arity = "0", description = "print A") boolean a ;
    @Option(names = { "-b"}, required = true, description = "pint B") boolean b ;
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use an `@ArgGroup`-annotated method, just like an `@ArgGroup`-annotated field.

For example:

```java
class SomeCommand implements Runnable {
    private Sample sample;

    @ArgGroup(exclusive = true, multiplicity = "1")
    void setGroup(Sample sample) {
        System.out.printf("setGroup was called with %s%n", sample);
        this.sample = sample;
    }

    static class Sample {
        @Option(names = "-a", required = true, arity = "0", description = "print A") boolean a ;
        @Option(names = "-b", required = true, description = "print B") boolean b ;

        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Sample[a=%s, b=%s]@%x", a, b, hashCode());
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.printf("In run, sample=%s%n", this.sample);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        //System.setProperty("picocli.trace", "DEBUG");
        new CommandLine(new SomeCommand()).execute("-a");    
    }
}
```

When I run this, I see the following output:

```
setGroup was called with Sample[a=false, b=false]@7de62196
In run, sample=Sample[a=true, b=false]@7de62196
```

So, you can use an `@ArgGroup`-annotated method; it will initially be invoked with a new instance, and this instance will be modified *after* the setter method was called.

(We can get more insight into what is happening under the hood by enabling picocli tracing.)